# Calling a web service using WS via an HTTP proxy

Tags: web-services, proxy, playframework-2.0

I am trying to call a web service from a playframework 2 application running in an environment where I need to go through a proxy server to access external web services. In my application.conf file I have added the following properties:

http.proxyPort=8000

http.proxyHost=myproxyhost.innitech.com

In my play application code I can access the system properties and verify they have been picked up. However, at runtime the proxy configuration is not being used. If I run the application in an environment where I do not need to use the proxy to access the service, the service call works fine.

Is it possible to call web services via a proxy using the play framework, and if so, how?

Here's an example of the call:

```
def watched(username: String, password: String): Promise[Seq[Repo]] = {
  val promiseResponse = WS.url(baseUrl + "/user/watched")
    .withAuth(username, password, com.ning.http.client.Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC)
    .get

    promiseResponse.map(_.json.as[Seq[Repo]])
}
```

The following stack trace represents what I see at run time:

```
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[Connec
tException: https://api.github.com/user]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:82) [p
lay_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:63) [p
lay_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:290) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:61) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:617) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]

    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:179) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: https://api.github.com/user
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationCo
mplete(NettyConnectListener.java:100) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultCh
annelFuture.java:397) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.addListener(DefaultChann
elFuture.java:143) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect
(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1004) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(N
ettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:829) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.j
ava:499) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:30) ~[na:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:480) ~[na
:1.6.0_25]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connec
t(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:142) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventS
unk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:105) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleDownstream(SslHandler.ja
va:459) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream
(OneToOneEncoder.java:55) ~[netty.jar:na]
```

Comment: Looking in the Play source code, the http client is instantiated wihout any context, e.g. lazy val client = new AsyncHttpClient(). I believe an AsyncHttpClientConfig needs to be built with the appropriate proxy context then passed to the AsynchHttpClient as a constructor parameter to properly initialize the client to go through a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

The current snapshot in github should fix this problem, as it builds a AsyncHttpClientConfig using the Play context, then initializes the AsynchHttpClient using the config:

```
lazy val client = {
  import play.api.Play.current
  val config = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()       
    .setConnectionTimeoutInMs(current.configuration.getMilliseconds("ws.timeout").getOrElse(120000L).toInt)
    .setFollowRedirects(current.configuration.getBoolean("ws.followRedirects").getOrElse(true))
    .setUseProxyProperties(current.configuration.getBoolean("ws.useProxyProperties").getOrElse(true))

  current.configuration.getString("ws.useragent").map { useragent =>
    config.setUserAgent(useragent)
}
new AsyncHttpClient(config.build())
```

}